# directive function Binding is not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have following directive definition and function binding.

```
function MainDashboard() {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: require('./dashboard.main.html'),
    controller: ["$rootScope","$log", "$localStorage", "UsersService", "SystemMessageService", "formatsSvc", MainController],
    controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
        main: '=',
        toggleObjectivesCallback: '&',
        findPromotions:'&'
    }
};
```

}

```
<button  id="btngetpromos" ng-click="mainCtrl.findPromotions();"></button>
```

And, while calling this directive I am passing function from parent directive, like this.

```
<main-dashboard find-promotions="mainCtrl.initGridOptions()" ></main-dashboard>
```

This method is not called when button is clicked. I don't know where I am doing wrong.
Pleas help

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need register it.

```
YourApp.directive('MainDashboard', MainDashboard);
```